# Tab escape quotations in VSCode

Tags: javascript, eclipse, visual-studio-code

In Eclipse, when typing a string I can tab out of the quotation marks (""). For example:
[image: tab escaping in Eclipse]

Note: when I type `"my cursor is inside the string"` I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to then type `now it isnt!`

Is there a way or extension to be able to do this in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the VSCode extension [Leaper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OnlyLys.leaper).

Comment: Does this let you use the tab escape though?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this extension creates the same Eclipse experience within VSCode.  For those coming from Eclipse it's perfect!

Comment: I think I found something, I'll include it in the answer.  But I recommend the extension.